# Возможно ли создавать и взаимодействовать с запароленными текстовыми файлами через Python?

Tags: python, txt

Я пишу игру при помощи pygame, для сохранения стандартных настроек сложности и прогресса игрока я решил использовать текстовые файлы. Очевидно, если не поставить пароли на текстовики, игрок сможет их изменить и сжульничать. Моя игра, конечно не очень сложная(буквально сапёр) и читерить в ней нет особого смысла, но всё же хотелось бы не давать игроку возможности манипуляции с файлами. Отсюда вытекает вопрос: "Возможно ли создавать и взаимодействовать с запароленными текстовыми файлами через Python?"

Если возможно, то буду благодарен за пример реализации.

Comment: Для этого даже не нужно "паролить" такие файлы. Достаточно посчитать контрольную сумму (например md5) от закрытой для изменения пользователем  информации вместе с "тайным паролем". Хранить ее (контрольную сумму) можно в том же файле. Остается придумать, где и как можно надежно скрыть от юзера "тайный пароль" (кстати, этот вопрос стоит столь же остро и в случае шифрации файла)

Comment: @avp Ваше решение мне подходит, но я всё же хотел, чтобы файл выглядел "красиво". Например: "мины: 20, ширина: 10, высота: 12". На счёт пароля: я хотел хранить его в самом коде. Подразумевается, что пользователь не настолько умён, чтобы переработать .exe  назад в .py

Comment: Так файл таким и будет. Вместе с результатами лучших игр. Только в конце добавится строчка `"scores hash: 1626....77373"`, вычисляемая по значению результатов. И вы ее проверяете (пересчитав при старте записанные результаты). Если не совпала -- ругаетесь, стираете подмененные результаты и начинаете с чистого листа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вам вариант зашифровать настройки?

```
import json
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

###########################################
# создание ключа шифрования
###########################################

# генерим ключ шифрования
key = Fernet.generate_key()
# пишем в файл setting1.bin ключ шифрования
with open(r'C:\ВАШ_ПУТЬ\setting1.bin', 'wb') as file_key:
    file_key.write(bytes(key))

############################################
# шифруем настройки и записываем в файл
############################################

# считываем ключ шифрования из файла setting1.bin
with open(r'C:\ВАШ_ПУТЬ\setting1.bin', 'rb') as file_key:
    key = file_key.read()

# Используем считанный ключ шифрования
encrypt_key = Fernet(key)

# например есть словарь с настройками
u_settings = {'set1': 10, 'set2': 'any', 'set3': 20}
# переводим настройки в байты
u_settings_b = json.dumps(u_settings, indent=2).encode('utf8')
# шифруем настройки
u_settings_enc = encrypt_key.encrypt(u_settings_b)
# записываем в файл setting2.bin зашифрованные настройки
with open(r'C:\ВАШ_ПУТЬ\setting2.bin', 'wb') as file_enc:
    file_enc.write(u_settings_enc)

############################################
# читаем настройки из файла и дешифруем
############################################

# считываем ключ шифрования из файла setting1.bin
key = None
with open(r'C:\ВАШ_ПУТЬ\setting1.bin', 'rb') as file_key:
    key = file_key.read()
# Используем считанный ключ шифрования
encrypt_key = Fernet(key)
# переменная для хранения зашифрованных настроек
u_settings_enc = None
# читаем из файла setting2.bin зашифрованные настройки
with open(r'C:\ВАШ_ПУТЬ\setting2.bin', 'rb') as file_enc:
    u_settings_enc = file_enc.read()
# расшифровываем настройки в байтах
u_settings_b = encrypt_key.decrypt(u_settings_enc)
# переводим настройки в словарь
u_settings = json.loads(u_settings_b)
```

Comment: Я не хотел прибегать к шифрованию файлов, но, видимо, всё же придётся. Спасибо за пример написания шифрования.